# Необходимо сделать SVG анимацию в которой используются картинки PNG/JPG. Или конвертировать JSON в SVG

Tags: json, svg, анимация

Пример того, что должно получиться:
https://static.everymatrix.com/cms2/tipico/_casino/D/D9FF6095F389B106BFC5DDF0E669E40F.svg

Я по большей части аниматор, а не программист, поэтому анимация с помощью рукописного кода мне не совсем подходит. Есть ли какое-то программное решение, позволяющее сделать подобную анимацию?

Я сделал то, что мне подходит, с помощью After Effect и плагина Bodymoving, и у меня получилась анимация в JSON файле. Можно ли его переконвертировать в анимированный SVG?

Comment: какой размер JSON получился? 800k или немного меньше? Сколько строк в файле JSON? Почему спрашиваю, так как видел несколько  таких вопросов  на EnSO с огромными файлами. Никто обычно не берется за такую адскую работу А анимация в рукописном варианте кажется совсем легкой и стандартной

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Мне нужно было сделать анимацию которая бы укладывалась бы в 60кб.
И у меня получился файл JSON размером 63кб. Основной вес файла это растровые картинки.

Собственно вот JSON файл
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/SxzA3xLiKi2j5g

Comment: понятно. В целом могу привести ответы на подобные вопросы на EnSO. Привожу по памяти - "Вполне реально сделать такую анимацию, но работа кропотливая, отнимет много времени. Делать бесплатно это не интересно"